# How can i show new added product on home page in magento

Tags: magento

Hi I want to show only two latest product on home page and remaining product in right side bar.
There is one method in my mind that either i will return only two element by following function 
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

But i think there should be a different approach for this.
Please put some light on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly shure what you are looking for. Do you want to know how to filter the product collection to get the newest products or do you want a module to do this?

Module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Inchoo/extension/2513/featured-products

Code to get a collection of the most recently added products.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
   ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
   ->setPageSize(2)
   ->setCurPage(1);
```

Comment: I need to diaplay all details of that latest products. What the Way? like price, image....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this Magento Wiki article:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page#new_products